# Disable future dates in JXDatePicker

Tags: java, datepicker

Hey guys I just want to know if how can I disable future dates in JXDatepicker.
By future dates I mean the days after the current system date. 
I really need it for a system I'm developing.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13226347/274350 - `picker.getMonthView().setUpperBound(new Date().getTime());` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> callB = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker param) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
                        setDisable(empty || item.compareTo(today) > 0);
                    }

                };
            }

        };
        selectedDate.setDayCellFactory(callB);
```

disable future date in date picker